# GNOME Power Saving Blank Screen causes gnome-shell to freeze

Tags: gnome, suspend

On Ubuntu 20.04, when the computer goes to the blank screen power saving mode and wakes back up, the gnome session currently running will freeze and require me to press CTRL + ALT + F4 and run `sudo killall -HUP gnome-shell`.

This is (obviously) really annoying, I've tried reinstalling gnome-shell multiple times to no success, hopefully one of your answers can help!